# Is it possible to convert an Open Face Font to TTF?

Tags: windows-xp, fonts, truetype-fonts

I purchased several fonts, and they installed in my fonts folder. They don't show up in any of my card programs or email, so they're of no use to me.

I see them listed and can use them in Notepad and Wordpad however.

Is there a way to convert the Open Face Font to a TTF font? Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: What is a "card program"?

Comment: What do you mean by "Open Face Font"? Do you mean an Open Type Font (`.otf` filetype)?

Answer (score 1):

A [quick google search](https://www.google.com/search?aq=0&oq=convert%20otf%20&q=convert%20otf%20to%20ttf) shows a variety of online tools to convert `otf` (open type fonts) to `ttf` (truetype fonts).

It's possible that the programs you're using don't properly support all font types, but if this is the case, you should complain to the manufacturer and ask for a refund. Font support should be handled automatically by the operating system.

Are you sure that your email and "card programs" don't just have a predefined list of fonts and don't allow you to use other fonts?